# I am having an error setting up my homepage on a local Node server using Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am having issues getting my web application to go to a homepage in my localhost. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var cors = require('cors');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.get('/home', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__filename + res.sendFile(path.relative('//../index.html')))
});
```

Comment: I think you're using twice res.sendFile please check it

Comment: Where is your `app.listen`?

Comment: I just put in the relevant code. I did two send files. It should work now

Comment: Ok now I have updated it: But it says TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Comment: app.get('/home', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__filename + path.relative('../index.html'))}
);

Comment: I updated it to remove the second res.sendFile but now I am getting a type error

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

try using : res.redirect('./index.html) instead of res.sendFile

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('./index.html)
});
```

Use, [express static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to redering html page from node.js

This [site](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/render-html-file-expressjs/) can be reference

Comment: The "path" argument must be of type string

Comment: You cannot directly rendering html page. You should using express static.
I have been editing my answer, hope can help you

Comment: You can render static html using res.sendfile. Redirect changes the url. For example if you redirect `'/'`, resulting url will be `localhost:3000/index.htl` but if you use the sendfile method, the html is rendered at `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

`path.relative('//../index.html')`   you have two forward slashes. It should be `path.relative('/../index.html')`